# Libgdx get a 3d model object 2D screen position

Tags: libgdx

Is there a way to get a 3d object position in the screen 2d? How?

I find unproject but it is the reverse that I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I find it:

```
            Vector3 pos2D = decal.getPosition().cpy();
            camera.project(pos2D);
            Logger.E(pos2D.x+" "+pos2D.y);
```